# How do I get the release X and Y position of a Drag?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I have a `DragListener` of which I would like to get the coordinates of where the view is released. But no matter where I drop it I get `x = 0` and `y = 0`. Obviously I am doing something wrong. How do I get the `x` and `y` of the release point?

```
this.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
    CustomIcon temp;
    CustomIcon dragging;
    Boolean thisOne;

    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

        for(int i= 0; i<mIcons.size();i++) {
            temp = mIcons.get(i);
            thisOne = temp.getDragging();
            if(thisOne) {
                dragging = temp;
            }
        }
        final int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED: {

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Dragging: "+v+" Width:"+dragging.getWidth()+ " X:"+dragging.getX(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
                dragging.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            } break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED: {

                dragging.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                dragging.stopDragging();

                // WHERE MY PROBLEM IS:
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Result: "+event.getResult()+" endX:"+(int) event.getX() + " endY:"+event.getY(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                final boolean dropped = event.getResult();

            } break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your case is listening to the wrong event.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/DragEvent.html#getX()

> #### public float getX ()
>
> Gets the X coordinate of the drag point. The value is only valid if the event action is ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION or ACTION_DROP.

Try changing your case to DragEvent.ACTION_DROP

Comment: Interesting..DragEvent.ACTION_DROP  never fires?

Comment: According to the documentation the event only fires if it was dropped on a view that is marked for being able to accept dragged content.

Comment: AH HA!  and all i have to do for that is set the listener to return true!  NICE!  thanks tencent!

Answer (score 0):

i had a problem like this. there is 3 important thing 1- set drag listener on parent view(for ex: linear layout or relative or .. ) 2- use ACTION_DROP for taking cooridinate x,y and not ACTION_DRAG_ENDED 3- set startDrag() on view that you want to drag it over parent. for example you can use setonlongclick() and set starDrag() inside longclick event